# VSTS Rest API fails from Azure logic app but succeeds from Postman

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-devops-rest-api

I have an Azure logic app that uses a "Send HTTP request" block to send a REST API call to VSTS to create an incident. The call fails with "HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.".

I tried the same request from Postman and the request succeeded. To make sure that I am making the same request I copied the URI, the headers, the body from the logic app.

How can I further investigate what is going on? Is there a log in VSTS where I can find out more info. Any help, any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Here you have the code of the "HTTP request block"

```
{
"inputs": {
    "method": "POST",
    "uri": "https://dev.azure.com/<your-vsts-organization>/<your-vsts-project>/_apis/wit/workitems/$Incident?api-version=4.1",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Basic .................................",
        "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json"
    },
    "body": "[\n    {\n    \"op\": \"add\",\n    \"path\": \"/fields/System.Description\",\n    \"from\": null,\n    \"value\": \"@{body('Parse_JSON_2')['Description']}\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"op\": \"add\",\n    \"path\": \"/fields/System.Title\",\n    \"from\": null,\n    \"value\": \"@{body('Parse_JSON_2')['Title']}\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"op\": \"add\",\n    \"path\": \"/fields/System.IterationPath\",\n    \"from\": null,\n    \"value\": \"<your-iteration-path>\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"op\": \"add\",\n    \"path\": \"/fields/System.AreaPath\",\n    \"from\": null,\n    \"value\": \"<your-area-path>\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"op\": \"add\",\n    \"path\": \"/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority\",\n    \"from\": null,\n    \"value\": \"2\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"op\": \"add\",\n    \"path\": \"/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity\",\n    \"from\": null,\n    \"value\": \"2 - High\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"op\": \"add\",\n    \"path\": \"/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.HowFound\",\n    \"from\": null,\n    \"value\": \"Azure Monitoring Alert\"\n  },\n]"
}
```

}

Here you have a screenshot of the request block:

[image]

Comment: Please give us some more relevant information. Try and provide a [mcve]. Important question: are you using the `visualstudio.com` URL, or the `dev.azure.com` url? Try the other one just to be sure.

Comment: I used "visualstudio.com"

Comment: I just tried it with dev.azure.com and I got the same result: "HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid"

Comment: Updated the question with the code of the "HTTP request block"

Answer (score 0):

We could easily do that with Azure Logic App - [Azure DevOps connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/).

I do a demo for creating an Azure DevOps workitem.

The following is the detail steps:

1.Create a logic App and send an http request to Azure DevOps action

[image]

2.Connect to Azure Devops and add the related information, for information please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

3. Test it on my side

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tom. I did all of that (I updated the question with a screenshot) but in my case it returns a 400. I was wondering if there is a log somewhere, maybe on the VSTS side where i can find more information about what is going on.

Comment: @NicolaeDaian I don't think there is a log  on Azure devops side that we could look into. Have you tried other Rest API? For example list projects `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=5.0-preview.3` It works correctly for me. When I try to use the API that you mentioned I got 404 error. ` Work item type Incident does not exist in project xxxxxx or you do not have permission to access it.` Would you mind sharing  the link of REST API you mentioned? As I mention that we could use the Azure Logic App Azure `Devops Connector` easily to call Azure Devops API.

Comment: @NicolaeDaian. Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful you could mark it as an answer to close it.

Comment: I am still waiting for an answer that would help me to investigate what is wrong. The API that I use works, because when I call it from Postman it produces the expected result. It doesn't work when called from Azure.

Comment: @NicolaeDaian Have you tried to call other API from the Logic App? If all of the Azure Devops api can't work on the logic App. I recommend that you create a [support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/) to get the help from Azure team.