# Authenticating into Azure DevOps from a Logic App

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I need to talk to my Azure DevOps instance from one of my Azure Logic Apps in order to perform some routine tasks (mainly, around reading a list of users through [Users - List API Call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)). Currently, I'm authenticating using a personal access token (PAT), however I wonder if there's a way to permission the Logic App in Azure DevOps in a way that wouldn't depend on my personal account (like PAT does). Any idea?

For example in Azure Automation, I can permission access for the logic app by the app's Identity Object ID, and access Azure Automation services through the REST API using the 'Managed Identity' as the Authentication type (in the HTTP action). Is there something like that possible in Azure DevOps?

Comment: Any update for this case, did below reply help you with above question?

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible to create something like "Managed Identity" in azure devops to permission logic apps access to azure devops instance.

You can add azure devops connector in logic apps to access azure devops services. You can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54080210/vsts-rest-api-fails-from-azure-logic-app-but-succeeds-from-postman?rq=1)

However i tested and found i cannot list Users by **sending http request to azure devops**, for microsoft host user ad data in different server domain "vssps". You might still need to use http request to call list User api and use basic Authentication(with user name and password) or PAT Authentication.